# Custom Annotations default values Webapplication

Tags: java, annotations

I started, out of curiosity, to read about Java Annotations and wanted to start experimenting with custom ones.

I always seem to come across one example, that every blogger and every tutorial seems to employ: Some kind of Author information for Methods, with an extensive main Method for aprsing and what not.

What i want to do is:

```
class myUSCitizen {
  @default(country="USA", token="GName")
  private String _mostCommonGivenName;+
  @Log
  public void setmostCommonGivenName(String Name){};

  @default (country="USA", token="age")
  @influence(token="age")
  @influence(token="salary")
  private int age;
  getter;setter;

  @influence(token="age")
  private boolean smoker;getter;setter;

  @calc(token="age")
  private int TTL;
  getter;setter;
}

@calculator
public class agecalculator{
   @calc(token="age")
   public int calculate(int[] args);
}
```

and everytime i instanciate a myHuman,

1) @default: i want it to look up in a configfile, and, if available, **insert default values at runtime** from that file.(a new USCitizen should for example per default be namend "Steve" and be age 35 or something)

2) the @Log annotation should make the application print a Logmessage **everytime the annotated method is called**

3) the @calc(token="age") annotation should look for a @Calculator class and pass all **members of the myHuman object annotated with @influence(token="age")** as arguments to the @calc(token="age") annotated method of the Calculator and set the value of TTL to the result

What i am asking for is:

Does anyone know documents or Tutorials that give information on how to handle the parts of my requirements that are **bold**.

and most of my problem, as i have very little experience with Webprojects, where would i put code that needs to be executed on Application Deployment/startup (the structure that holds the Calculators etc.)

I don't know if anything of this is possible, so if you happen to know that something is definetly NOT possible, please be clear about it^^.

I am aware of the fact that i could do all of that relativley easy without annotations,that some parts are absolutely unnecessary and that there are Frameworks that do parts of this, but this is meant to be an experiment, please no answers on how i should use Spring. for this and that^^

Thanks in advance for any Links or hints.

Comment: You have a massive mess of requirements here, from compile-time code generation to run-time code manipulation to an annotation aware factory of some sort. It doesn't, to me, look like you've read nearly enough to understand what you are asking. Further, as annotations are classes, they should be in `PascalCase`.

Comment: It is intended to be a "mess" of requirements, to encourage everyone who might have a source on any of them to share them. I know, i have obviously not read enough, because I am asking for sources to read about exactly the aspects you named^^

Answer (score -1):

I advice you not to use the annotation Java system to achieve this but aop, like AspectJ. It will be easier to programm than an annotation processor, more maintainable and more efficient. You can find the [AspectJ project here](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/).

Comment: Thanks, but as i stated, i know that this can relatively easy be done without annotations, but i want to learn about annotations and runtime /compiletime codemanipulation, just for the sake of learning about it, not so much to efficiently solve the meaningless example i provided

Comment: It was only an advice. And in your case AOP won't only be more efficient but far more easy to program too

Comment: i know, my point is more like: english is far easier to learn and more commonly spoken than arabic. which does not at all help me if i want to learn arabic^^

Comment: I don't advice you another language but a another "tool". It's completely different. But no problem, good luck ;)